# Auto range based structured bindings with vector

Tags: c++, c++17, structured-bindings

I'm trying to loop over a vector of tuples:

```
std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> tupleList;
```

By using a range based for loop with structured bindings:

```
for (auto&& [x, y, z] : tupleList) {}
```

But Visual Studio 2017 15.3.5 gives the error:

> cannot deduce 'auto' type (initializer required)

But the following does work:

```
for (auto&& i : tupleList) {
    auto [x, y, z] = i;
}
```

Why is that?

Comment: Why are you using `&&` and not `&`?

Comment: @Charles `&&` will work even if elements are const or temporaries

Comment: VS bug, it should work. Was even one of the motivations of the language feature (iterating over a map)!

Comment: Would `const auto` be ok as well? @GuillaumeRacicot

Comment: @Charles in that case, you won't be able to mutate elements, or forward them to a function that either take a const reference or a mutable reference. The thing is, `auto&&` simply works, and works everywhere, even in fully generic code.

Comment: @Charles `for (auto&& a : ..)` even has its own very standard proposal for a shortcut to `for (a : ..)` exploiting its universality. Refused though IIRC.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It does work, but the intellisense doesn't use the same compiler:
[image]

So even with the red lines and error shown in the editor it does compile with the `ISO C++17 Standard (/std:c++17)` switch.

I compiled the following program:

```
#include <vector>
#include <tuple>

std::vector<std::tuple<int, int, int>> tupleList;
//By using a range based for loop with structured bindings :

int main()
{
    for(auto&&[x, y, z] : tupleList) {}
}
```

Visual Studio version:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2017 Preview (2) Version 15.4.0
>   Preview 3.0 VisualStudio.15.Preview/15.4.0-pre.3.0+26923.0

cl version:

> 19.11.25547.0

From command line:

```
>cl test.cpp /std:c++17
Microsoft (R) C/C++ Optimizing Compiler Version 19.11.25547 for x64
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

test.cpp
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Preview\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.11.25503\include\cstddef(31): warning C4577: 'noexcept' used with no exception handling mode specified; termination on exception is not guaranteed. Specify /EHsc
Microsoft (R) Incremental Linker Version 14.11.25547.0
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.

/out:test.exe
test.obj
```